# Nginx returns 502 bad gateway

Tags: php, nginx

During high server load, connections made through browser slow in performance and sometimes get 502 bad gateway. Server runs PHP under Nginx.

I mentioned connections made through browser because only browsers are affected by this issue during high server load. API requests made through iOS are unaffected by this problem at all times, iOS request never gets the 502 bad gateway response nor does suffer any performance issues at any given time.

**The Nginx error log shows periodically only this error:**

```
1637#0: *9281373 connect() to unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/***/php-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream
```

Comment: seems like your PHP fpm process get stopped continuously.

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim yes. So what shall I configure / fix?